# How can I show total number of successful user's order?

Tags: php

I had created a Panel for the users and I wanted to display how many orders did user paid. But I don't know how can I display them.
I'd used this code on my panel, but it displays all of the orders and it doesn't filter the successful orders.

```
<?php $current_user_id = get_current_user_id(); ?>
<?php wc_get_customer_order_count($current_user_id); ?>
```

Can somebody Help me?

Comment: Please provide more detail on your code and the project.

Comment: I wanted to Create something like this on my panel:
number of total products that bought from the user

Answer (score 0):

You may try this code

```
function completed_orders_by_costumer_id(){

    global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_wc_order_stats WHERE status = 'wc-completed' AND WHERE customer_id=".get_current_user_id();
$row = $wpdb->get_results($query);
$total = count($row);

    return $total;
}
```